# How definitive are "patterns" in grammar across languages?

Tags: syntax, morphology, grammar

So when you learn a new language from English like Spanish in school, they make it seem like "hey there's these clear patterns and rules once learned you'll master spanish". So you learn the verb conjugations for some simple verbs that all fit the same pattern. But then second year comes around and you learn that there are all kinds of edge cases and slight divergences from teh "main" patterns which you just learned.

With that in mind, I've been looking around at every language I can find. Hebrew, Greek, Latin, Sanskrit, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Cambodian, Thai, Telugu, Tamil, Nahuatl, Zapotec, Piraha, Ancient Egyptian, Yoruba, Igbo, Xhosa, Armenian, Arabic, Inuktitut, Basque, Georgian, Sumerian, Norwegian, Old English, Navajo, Cherokee, Tibetan, etc.

I haven't looked too closely at the grammars yet, but I have seen them and tried scanning them to see if they have a highly "normal" structure. By that I mean like a set of rules that everything follows, with no edge cases. Or if there are edge cases, there are clear rules to them (like changing the following letter based on the previous letter in verb conjugations).

From what it seems, especially in the "main" ones like Hebrew, Sanskrit, and Chinese, is that there is **no standard set of patterns**. These books are all saying "Sanskrit has 3 genders and 9 x and 12 y for every noun, and 4 this and 5 that for every verb, etc." Or for Tibetan, "there are 3 verb forms and they come in these flavors: a, b, c. etc.". But then my experience is something like this....

> THE FIRST VERB I PICK OUT OF THE HAT DOESN'T FIT THE PATTERN

The second one doesn't either. These turn out to be edge cases. The third one doesn't either, that belongs to this *other* class we don't learn until Graduate school. Etc.

So....

What I'm wondering is if these "patterns" (so to speak, they are not *computationally rigorous* patterns in my opinion) are more just this:

> VAGUE CLASSIFICATION OF SPEECH/WRITING DONE AFTER THE FACT

That is, these "rules" are more just like "Hey, it *looks* like these verbs all have the same pattern" or "It *seems* like this is a group of related words". But in reality, it is just something human minds have classified into patterns....

> IT'S NOT BUILT INTO THE LANGUAGE ITSELF

Instead, it's the result of evolution or something, and *after the fact* we "find" these patterns. More accurately, we try to come up with patterns in the language, even though it wasn't **designed** that way.

Is that more or less an accurate reading?

Basically, the people who write these grammars are trying to make sense of languages that *don't have an inbuilt set of rules predefined for them*. In doing so, they come up with these "rules" and "patterns" so it is "easier" to teach (I would say it makes it harder). Every language listed above, and every language other than perhaps modern constructed languages, don't have predefined rules. Is that correct?

But what about Sanskrit, or a few others? I've heard about how there were ancient grammar books written. Does this mean it was constructed with rules? Or no, they are just like modern grammarians and analyzed their language *after the fact* that it was already in existence.

If there are languages which have predefined patterns (before their existence), what are they and are there any edge cases?

I am trying to go through a grammar and learn the patterns, but then I am finding really it's a bunch of fluff and almost it would be better to just figure out the patterns on your own and be provided with a very large word list.

So then generally I guess part of the question could be, **what is the purpose of grammars**? The stated purpose is "to define the rules of the language". But these aren't *rules*, give me a break. These are more like "shared traits" of word forms rather than *rules*. With shared traits you can't use them as *rules*. Rules don't have edge-cases. Unless that is part of the rule too! With shared traits, you can only use them as a hint to the analysis of new word forms. And maybe "hey, this uses the same pattern in 2 of the 120 cases I've seen, that makes it Class A!". But that is definitely not making it a rule, more like a *coincidence* or *borrowing*.

I have to say, it would be way better to see the full notes of every word recorded by the linguist than to have the grammar as the final source of truth. The word list is the final source of truth, and the collected sentences! But they usually are few in the grammar books in comparison to the length of the grammar book. 10,000 sentences and 100,000 words might be a good start.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand this question at all. How can a language have predefined patterns "(before their existence)"?

Comment: By sitting down and mapping it out in advance?

Comment: In advance of what, though?

Comment: By constructing the language from nothing :) Are all natural languages not constructed? Is that a fact?

Comment: That is indeed a fact!

Comment: Okay then, this means grammars don't have rules. They lie. They have "patterns".

Comment: I'm working on an answer now, but grammars have rules just as much as physics and chemistry have rules.

Comment: Yeah, but we call those "laws" because they are USEFUL 99.999% of the time. Whereas in my case every new verb in every language I lookup has something that breaks the rule I just learned. So these rules are [not useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_verb_paradigm). A better word linguists should be using is "pattern", which a [few do](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Sentence_Patterns). Grammar points and patterns.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because honestly it feels like a rather argumentative "hey give me a pat on the back and agree with me that grammars suck" essay, not really a question. There's a question at the end but seriously, that's not even the question. Besides, that grammars exist to provide "rules" sounds very arguable, and at the very least, one of many definitions of grammar that could be proposed; the question is loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> More accurately, we try to come up with patterns in the language, even though it wasn't **designed** that way.

Absolutely.

Pretty much all of modern linguistics is *descriptive* as opposed to *prescriptive*. In other words, it's not about making up rules that people have to follow—it's about inventing rules that explain the data we observe.

Think of it like physics. Isaac Newton "invented" gravity—he came up with some very famous rules that explained how it worked. But before Newton, objects didn't just hover in midair; Newton didn't change the way the world worked, he only documented what already existed. Linguistics is the same.

And Newton's law of gravitation, like pretty much anything in linguistics, is a *model*. It may miss some nuance, or fall apart on certain edge cases, but that's okay—the point is to come up with an explanation that covers as much of the data as possible, as elegantly and simply as possible. We know nowadays that Newton's law of gravitation isn't perfect, and has some pretty serious flaws in it, but despite those flaws it got humanity to the moon and back.

> Basically, the people who write these grammars are trying to make sense of languages that *don't have an inbuilt set of rules predefined for them*. In doing so, they come up with these "rules" and "patterns" so it is "easier" to teach (I would say it makes it harder). Every language listed above, and every language other than perhaps modern constructed languages, don't have predefined rules. Is that correct?

Depends what you mean by predefined. Languages tend to follow patterns, not because some ancient language-planner laid out those patterns for them, but because it makes things easier for the learners and speakers. In English, there's a general rule that you make nouns plural by adding a special morpheme to the end, and that morpheme can take four different forms, depending on the final sound in the word. This rule doesn't work 100% of the time (child~children, goose~geese), but it's "real" in the sense that children learn it, internalize it, and can apply it in situations they've never encountered before (look up "the wug test" for details).

And languages do evolve over time—they evolve *really quickly*, in fact, compared to biological evolution, and there's *enormous* selection pressure on them every minute of every day. Sometimes this evolution makes them more regular: you mention Spanish's *-ar -er -ir* conjugation patterns, which evolved out of Latin's system of *four* conjugations (the "consonant conjugation", the least regular/predictable one, got broken up and absorbed into the others), which evolved out of Proto-Indo-European's whole mess of different paradigms and derivations. Sometimes it makes them less regular, when sound changes obscure something that used to be regular and make it "opaque". It's always a compromise between regularity (regular, easy-to-learn patterns) and efficiency (conveying information as quickly and reliably as possible), and trade-offs always have to be made.

> So then generally I guess part of the question could be, **what is the purpose of grammars**?

To document the structure and usage of a language, as completely and succinctly as possible.

Usually this involves giving broad generalities ("Latin nouns ending in *-a* are feminine"), which work 90% of the time, and then later filling in the edge cases ("…except for Greek borrowings and a handful of fossilized forms"). It's the same reason physics students learn Newton's law of gravitation before Einstein's: 90% of the time, F=GMm/r² will get you the answer you need.

> I have to say, it would be way better to see the full notes of every word recorded by the linguist than to have the grammar as the final source of truth. The word list is the final source of truth, and the collected sentences! But they usually are few in the grammar books in comparison to the length of the grammar book. 10,000 sentences and 100,000 words might be a good start.

You're right, the raw data collected by a field linguist is usually more complete and more authoritative than a grammar. But you're severely underestimating how much data is needed to fully learn a language!

Think of how long it takes children to learn their first languages. That's years and years of time spent hearing the language used just about every hour of every day. Evidence shows, that's how much data it takes to truly learn (i.e. have an accurate mental model of) a language. Because you need to not only learn every pattern and rule and law in the grammar, but also all the exceptions, all the variations, all the possible changes and slips and idiosyncracies and styles and accents that make up what we call "English".

So while no grammar is complete, they tend to be an acceptable compromise: if I want to know something about Swahili, it'll be much, much easier for me to find a good grammar and look up the appropriate chapter than to move to Kenya and spend a decade listening to people speak! Just like in physics, people around the world are constantly working on building newer and better models for language. But we're not at the point where every detail of a language can fit into a single book, or even a set of books, and it's unclear if we ever will be.

And, crucially—**learning a language is fundamentally about learning patterns**. Take a random sentence from this answer. Odds are you've never seen that exact sentence before in your life. Odds are that sentence has never been written down before by anyone in the universe! Yet you can read it no problem. Why? *Because of the mental rules that form your knowledge of English.* Those are the rules that linguists try to document. It's been proven that you *don't* memorize the plural for every word individually—instead, you remember a few special cases and exceptions, and learn a rule for all the rest. (Again, look up "the wug test".) This is why grammars are pretty much universally regarded as A Good Thing, even if they always have to rely on generalizations that don't work in every instance.

Comment: But if we had a list of 10,000 sentences and 100,000 words defined with their meaning in unicode, it would be pretty easy to write a grammar automatically from the data. I wish they had thought of this before spending the decades compiling a grammar .. But I guess it was useful in the interim. Now to go back and do the work again...

Comment: @LancePollard (Added an extra paragraph now btw.) I'm curious, why would Unicode help anything? But regardless—it's not hard to get a list of 10,000 English sentences and 100,000 English words with their definitions. Yet nobody's ever built a computer that can understand English as well as a five-year-old child. Coming up with a grammar is *really really hard!*

Comment: English is fine, there's plenty of data, it's the rest of the languages which are hard, like most of the ones I listed above.

Comment: I just mean (by unicode) in digital text format (i.e. not scanned/junky pdf). I have seen plenty of grammars and dictionaries in PDF forms, but few in digital text (etext, unicode, what have you) format.

Comment: @LancePollard Data's plentiful nowadays! For example, it's easy to grab a French Bible (~700000 words) off the internet, and look up French words in Wiktionary. If you think you can use that to automatically come up with a grammar for French, I invite you to try—it's a *lot* harder than it seems.

Comment: Wiktionary is good, yeah. The bible is a good resource, but there are only [~100 public domain bibles in text format](https://github.com/7-rabbit/8-text/tree/master/content/bible). The data is far from plentiful in other languages, I have begun collecting dictionaries. I found most languages have a dictionary online with an unparsable PDF (some don't even have that as they were not part of the Google Book project, like !Xoo, or even Xhosa), but grammars in a parsable format? Forget about it :)

Comment: @LancePollard [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1831/), also. Somewhere around the 80s people thought it would be easy for computers to learn language, since it's so easy for humans; thirty years later, our hardware has eclipsed anything Star Trek ever dreamed of, but a computer that can hold a conversation about arbitrary topics in fluent English is still fantasy.

Comment: Hahaha, nice :)

Comment: If we had the data of the _meaning_ of words in parsable format, as part of the dictionary/corpus, then we could build a grammar from it pretty easily. But to then take the grammar and generate conversation, well yeah that is a whole different  problem. You have to model reality or something to do that!

Comment: @LancePollard Again, I invite you to try. A big part of writing a grammar is finding patterns, and finding patterns automatically is far from trivial.

Comment: @LancePollard Scraping Wiktionary isn't difficult. Pick French or something like that and you should have plenty of data.

Comment: +1. "Think of it like physics" - what I find most fascinating about linguistics and languages is that, unlike with physics, **humans** here are trying to describe and explain a phenomenon created, developed and maintained (so to say) by **humans** in the first place..